# How do I use PropertyMock to return requests response attributes in a pytest unit test?

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm using the [pytest-mock wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) with pytest.

I can't get a PropertyMock to work with the [requests package](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests).

Here's an example of a function I'm trying to unit test:

```
def get():
    url = f'http://foo.bar/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        sys.exit(1)
    return response.text
```

And here's my attempt at a unit test:

```
import pytest
import my_module
import requests

def test_get(mocker, monkeypatch):
    response_mock = mocker.MagicMock()
    status_code_mock = mocker.PropertyMock(return_value=200)
    text_mock = mocker.PropertyMock(return_value='xyz')
    type(response_mock).status_code = status_code_mock
    type(response_mock).text = text_mock
    monkeypatch.setattr(requests, 'get', response_mock)

    my_module.get()
```

The test fails because 200 is not returned by `response.status_code`.

I tried putting a PDB breakpoint after the `requests.get()` call, and checked the response.status_code attribute myself in PDB. I get a MagicMock object:

```
(Pdb) response.status_code
<MagicMock name='mock().status_code' id='4487925656'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the *return value* of a `requests.get` call which is assigned to `response` variable.

In this line:

```
monkeypatch.setattr(requests, 'get', response_mock)
```

You replaced the get method itself with a mock. But what you probably wanted was to replace it with something which *returns* your response mock when called, for example:

```
monkeypatch.setattr(requests, 'get', lambda url: response_mock)
```

As an aside, consider using existing pytest plugins/fixtures for this code. [`requests_mock`](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mocker.html) and [`responses`](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) are both good choices.  After `pip install requests_mock`, for example, your test could look like this instead:

```
def test_get_better(requests_mock):
    requests_mock.get("http://foo.bar/", text="xyz")
    response_text = my_module.get()
    assert response_text == "xyz"
```

Comment: Thank you! Changing the line to `monkeypatch.setattr(requests, 'get', lambda url: response_mock)` allows the test to pass. Please add this to your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: OK, I added the monkeypatch to this answer.  However, since I think using a requests mock fixture is a much better approach here, I also added an example of how to do that.